# Delay execution of Javascript code until image loads

Tags: javascript, promise

My javascript code requires an image to load before it can proceed with the rest of the script:

```
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.onload = function() {
   executeRemainingCode();
};
myImage.src = myImgURL;

function executeRemainingCode() {
// 2,000 lines of remaining code to execute
}
```

It works fine, however, I would prefer not to wrap thousands of lines of remaining code into a function. It makes the indentation and parentheses more complicated for the entire script.

Is there a way to delay execution of the remaining code, without wrapping it all in a function?

Comment: If that's suitable to you, you can wait for the 'load' event, it will be triggered when everyting is loaded including images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use promise

@Sebastian Simon You can simply use [top-level await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top_level_await) instead.

```js
const ImagePromise = (src) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  const myImage = new Image();
  
  myImage.onload = () => {
   resolve();
  };

  myImage.src = src;
})

await ImagePromise(myImageUrl)

// 2,000 lines of remaining code to execute
```

Comment: A promise all call might be good too

Comment: _“but you still need to wrap with an async function”_ — No, you can simply use [top-level `await`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top_level_await) instead.

Comment: This is really cool. Worked perfectly. I was not aware of await. Very helpful, thank you!